# Accessing context property of a function object | How to?

Tags: javascript

Each function object should have two "hidden" properties ( per JavaScript The Good Parts, The Functions Chapter )

```
context
```

and

```
code
```

Is there a way to access these properties?

Comment: I think the book is meaning something more *conceptual* then `Foo.context` and `Foo.code`.

Comment: I don't know I always had some kind of feeling that the code was stored as a string somewhere that I could access.  Seems like dynamically compiled languages like to make most things into a string...or so I would blindly intuit.

Comment: `func.toString()` gets you the source code in certain environments. Not sure what "context" refers to in the book, though.

Comment: @pimvdb: I was *guessing* `this`.

Comment: context is related to how the function is invoked...4 ways - function invocation, method invocation, constructor invocation, and apply invocation.

Comment: @HiroProtagonist: Then no, you can't get that information because it depends on the way it was called. Given a function you can call it as any in those ways.

Comment: What this references is determined by the invocation type I think.

Comment: Right...but I think when it is called...I'm pretty sure per the book..it stores this context in the `Function Object`

Comment: @pimvdb You can [bind](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind) a function to a given context

Comment: @dystroy: The function `.bind` returns doesn't have a `this` value. It just calls the original function with the predefined `this` value, but it's not a property of that function. You can of course create your own `.bind` function and expose the `this` value as a property as well.

Comment: "The simplest use of bind() is to make a function that, no matter how it is called, is called with a particular this value". It may not be a readable property but it's definitely a property of the new function.

Comment: @dystroy: Yes, in a sense it's a "property". Like the OP's question the difference lies in what kind of property is meant (conceptual vs `func.prop`).

Comment: That's always the risk with [non practical questions](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#dontask). They may be interesting or pointless...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, you can access the function code pretty easily - by using [toString()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/toString) (or Mozilla's non-standard [toSource()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/toSource)):

```
var x = function() { alert('Here is my happy function'); };
console.log(x.toString());
```

As for context, I suppose DC meant more than simple `this`, and actually wrote about Execution Context.

**UPDATE:** Have found an interesting snippet in [ES5 specification](http://es5.github.com/#x13.2), where these two properties are actually described in some details - and not as abstract concepts:

> **13.2 Creating Function Objects**
>
> Given an optional parameter list specified by FormalParameterList, a
>   body specified by *FunctionBody*, a Lexical Environment specified by
>   *Scope*, and a Boolean flag Strict, a Function object is constructed as
>   follows:
>
> ...
>
> Set the [[Scope]] internal property of F to the value of Scope.
>
> ...
>
> Set the [[Code]] internal property of F to FunctionBody.

At the same time:

> Lexical Environments and Environment Record values are purely
>   specification mechanisms and need not correspond to any specific
>   artefact of an ECMAScript implementation. It is impossible for an
>   ECMAScript program to directly access or manipulate such values.

So I guess that closes the question about accessing `Scope` property of function.

As for `Code` property, its read-only accessing with `toString()`, as was rightly noticed by Matt, is implementation-dependent - yet is more often implemented than not. )

Comment: Note that this isn't part of any standard... although all modern browsers do seem to have this behaviour.